# Controller Post action not getting view Model ASP.NET Core Razor pages

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-core, model-binding

#### I am creating a razor form that takes options from a list from the model and displays radio buttons and a text input. when I submit, the post method has a view model where all properties are null. how can I fix it?

#### my razor view

```
@model CreateBallotViewModel
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-1">
        <h4 class="mb-3">@Model.elect.Question</h4>
        <div class="my-3">
            @using (Html.BeginForm(actionName: "CreateBallot", controllerName: "Account", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                @foreach (var opt in Model.options)
                {
                    <div class="form-check">
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(expression: model => model.choice, opt.OptionName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-check-input" })
                        @*@Html.LabelFor(expression: model => @opt.OptionName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-check-label" })
                        <input name="credit" asp-for="choice" type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="@opt.OptionName">*@
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="credit">@opt.OptionName</label>
                    </div>

                }
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input name="credit" asp-for="choice" type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="credit">Neutral</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="cc-cvv" class="form-label">Tracking Number</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc-cvv" placeholder="" required="" asp-for="tracking">
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        Security code required
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr class="my-4">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Cast Ballot</button>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## My model

```
using System;
namespace electronicvotingfyp.Models
{
    public class CreateBallotViewModel
    {
        public List<ElectionOption> options { get; set; }
        public Election elect { get; set; }
        public string choice;
        public string tracking;
        //vote encrypted
        //signed vote
        //keys
    }
}
```

#### my controller with the get and post actions

```
 [Authorize]
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult CreateBallot(int ElectionId)
        {

            List<ElectionOption> electionOptions = new List<ElectionOption>();
            Election election = null;
            DbContextOptions<electronicvotingfypIdentityDbContext> options = new DbContextOptions<electronicvotingfypIdentityDbContext>();
            using (var db = new electronicvotingfypIdentityDbContext(options))
            {

                election = db.Elections.Single(u => u.ElectionId == ElectionId);
                electionOptions  = db.Options.Where(p => p.Election  == election).ToList();
            }

            CreateBallotViewModel cbm = new CreateBallotViewModel() { options = electionOptions ,elect = election };

            return View(cbm);
        }
        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult CreateBallot(CreateBallotViewModel cbm)
        {
            ElectionKeySystem keys = null;
            DbContextOptions<electronicvotingfypIdentityDbContext> options = new DbContextOptions<electronicvotingfypIdentityDbContext>();
            using (var db = new electronicvotingfypIdentityDbContext(options))
            {

                keys = db.ElectionKeys.Single(u => u.RelatedElection.ElectionId == cbm.elect.ElectionId);
               
            }
            PemReader pr = new PemReader(new StringReader(keys.publicKey));
            AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)pr.ReadObject();
            //ElGamalPublicKeyParameters publicKeyParams = (ElGamalPublicKeyParameters)keyPair.Public;

            ElectionKeySystemContrroller ks = new ElectionKeySystemContrroller(keyPair);
            byte[] inputChoice = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cbm.choice);
            byte[] inputTracking = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cbm.tracking);
            byte[] encryptedChoice = ks.Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cbm.choice), 0, inputChoice.Length);

            return View(cbm);
        }
    }
```

#### I tried changing the form input which were initially html tags to Html.RadioFor. I also tried having new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" } as a parameter for Html.BeginForm. I also tried hidden fields for the properties I had set before.

Answer (score 1):

Please give the getter and setter of properties

```
public string Tracking { get; set; }
public string Tracking { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Nahid.

I reproduced your issue in my side and without `{get; set;}`, we can see in the request context that the form already submit data to the action but can't bind to the model.

By the way, in your controller you had `cbm.elect.ElectionId`, but in your form code, you didn't contain `elect.ElectionId`, so you also need to put code like this into the form, or the `cbm.elect` still be null.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(actionName: "CreateBallot", controllerName: "home", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <input style="display:none" asp-for="@Model.elect.ElectionId" />
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I actually did this : <input asp-for="@Model.elect.ElectionId" type="hidden" />
                <input asp-for="@Model.elect.Creator" type="hidden" />
                <input asp-for="@Model.elect.StartDate" type="hidden" />
                <input asp-for="@Model.elect.EndDate" type="hidden" />
                <input asp-for="@Model.elect.Title" type="hidden" />
                <input asp-for="@Model.elect.Question" type="hidden" />
                <input asp-for="@Model.elect.Participations" type="hidden" />
                <input asp-for="@Model.elect.Options" type="hidden"

Comment: when I added it elect is no longer null but everything else still is. I  replaced my foreach:  for (int i = 0; i < Model.options.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input asp-for="Model.options[i]" type="hidden" />
                        Html.RadioButtonFor(expression: model => model.choice, Model.options[i].OptionName, htmlAttributes: new { class = "form-check-input" })
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="credit"> Model.options[i].OptionName</label>
                    </div>
 }

Comment: Hi, you can edit your code in the question and update your latest issue. In my test, adding `{ get; set; }` will solve the issue for not binding `choice, tracking`, adding `input hidden` will solve null issue for `elect`.

Comment: It is all solved with these edits many thanks!

Comment: I'm glad to see your issue all solved : ) could you pls mark one of the answer(by click the √ besides the answer) to end this question? thanks in advance.